# Node js request Getting ETIMEDOUT 'ip address'

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm, httprequest

**Her's what i am doing in the code**

i am Reading a text file with around 3500 links then i am reading each link , filtering the one i want and doing a request to get the status code, link, and page title (using cheerio). after around the looping the 100th or 200th link i get the "connect ETIMEDOUT 40...:443". links look good. Whats going on here? is the web server kicking me out thinking its is a DDOS?, i am doing this for a company i work for and this is not the intention obviously. if any of you want to test with large amount links , i used https://hackertarget.com/extract-links/ to get the links then put it in a text file.

**Here is my code**

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

var main = [];
var linkdata = [];

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/Jay/Documents/Javascript/crawl/links.txt'),
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

rl.on('line', (link) => {
  if (link.startsWith('https://www.example.com')) {
    var encodeLink = encodeURI(link)
    request(encodeURI(encodeLink), function (error, response, body) {
      console.log("Link: ",encodeLink)
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error:Request " + error);
      }
      // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)

      if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        // Parse the document body
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var Status_200 = {
          "status Code": response.statusCode,
          "Page title:": $('title').text(),
          "Original Link": encodeLink,
        }
        main.push(Status_200)
      }

      if (response.statusCode === 302 || response.statusCode === 404 || response.statusCode === 500) {
        // Parse the document body
        var Status_Errors = {
          "status Code": response.statusCode,
          "Page title:": $('title').text(),
          "Original Link": encodeLink,
        }
        main.push(Status_Errors)

      }
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(main))
      fs.writeFile("C:/Users/Jay/Documents/Javascript/crawl/output.json", JSON.stringify(main), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
      });
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Try setting a timeout on your requests.

Comment: @devio i put a timeout like this, but still getting it `var encodeLink = encodeURI(link);
    var options={
      url:encodeLink,
      timeout:100000
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {`

Comment: I would probably make everything async using promises and set an await delay (using an async timeout function) between **every** request, around 2 seconds. I know that's 7K secs (2 hours) but if you're scraping a website and you don't have access to the configuration files, things may get weird and messy.

Comment: @devio ah i was hoping you not say that, not very good at writing promises especially with new async await, Let me take a stab at it.  if you can do a quick demo with my code, would appreciate it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a try catch around since using async to see if that helps with memory error you getting, probably good practice anyway

```js
try {
        const body = response.data;
        if (response.status === 200) {
          //do ur thing
        }
  
        if (response.status === 302 || response.status === 404 || response.status === 500) {
          // Parse the document body
                   //do ur thing

        }
            fs.writeFile("C:/Users/T440/Documents/crawl/output.json", JSON.stringify(main), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
          });
      } catch (error) {

                   //catch them erros

        }
        main.push(Status_ErrorsCatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

With some suggestions from the comments i slowed down the process with readline async iterator structure as well as using axios for more promise friendly

Here is sample of how i fixed the  ETIMEDOUT 'ip address' issue, i am having memmory issue now but the original problem is solved i think

```js
async function processLineByLine() {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/T440/Documents/crawl/links.txt'),
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    if (line.startsWith('https://www.example.com')) {
      var encodeLink = encodeURI(line);
    
      const response =  await axios.get(encodeLink).catch((err)=>{
```